# Validate paypal pay id passed by Android in Magento site

Tags: php, android, magento, paypal

We are making an Android app for our Magento 1.9 site. On our site, we already integrated Paypal successfully.

In the app, the customer is able to do payments, and, using the Paypal SDK, we are getting the transaction id in app. The Android team will pass the transaction id to Magento and in Magento we need to validate payment.

Our Android team needs an API from the Magento side.

How can we do this?

---

We are getting the **transaction id** from [paypal sdk](https://github.com/sassybee/PayPal-Android-SDK-master) after completion of order.

Please visit [github link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/main/java/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/SampleActivity.java) & search for "server for verification" (using CTRL+F).

In the link, they mentioned we have to verify with the server, so how can I verify with server after a payment is done through app?

---

The Paypal team sent us a Request Sample:

```
$apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
        "<CLIENT_ID>", "<CLIENT_SECRET>"));

$payment = Payment::get('PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI', $apiContext);
```

They say we have to send a request to PayPal using the above sample code.

Once we pass `pay id`, then PayPal will respond with full payment details.

how to use the above code in our site?

The Paypal team gave us this [github code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/GetPayment.php).

They say I have to use the whole [SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) for getting payment details. How do I use it in Magento?

Comment: What do you mean by "in magento we need to validate it"? You want Android application to send transaction ID to magento, magento then to pull transaction details from PayPal and record payment in magento?

Comment: @BorisSavic you are right.

Comment: @BorisSavic please check updated question .

Comment: Here is PayPal PHP SDK: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK and on this page on right side if you click PHP you can see how to use it via composer https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Comment: Here I have got solution
[enter link description here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102128/how-to-create-order-with-payment-method-paypal-express-in-magento-through-cust?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Here I got the solution hope this will help you. [Solution](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102128/how-to-create-order-with-payment-method-paypal-express-in-magento-through-cust?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following explanations are based on the use case that, you've PayPal (either Express Checkout or Payment Pro) enabled in your Magento Web store, yet additionally integrating Mobile Native SDK in your client APP (rather than using the exsing Magento PayPal flow, embedded into a webview in your APP).

1. Verifying the payment (after your Client APP got the `payment-id` in the response) is important for fraud prevention. Mobile APP interacts with PayPal servers independently, and you would not want to deliver the goods/service upon a mobile API response (which is easy to replicate) without server (your Magento server) verification against the actual payment contents.
2. Apparently Magento doesn't come with this part of codes in the PayPal module and you need to implement your own, but yet you won't necessarily have to import the whole RESTful SDK just for a single payment look-up API call. 
   Everything is based on JSON requests & JSON parsing, it works as long as you follow the PayPal RESTful payload scheme [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#api-operations), and initiate the request with `curl` statements.
3. Checklist on a payment after your server obtains the details can be also found [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/?mark=validating%20payment).

Additional best practice for server-end implementation:

- Store the payment-id e.g. `id": "PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI"` in your database along with the order data entry;
- Store the `debug-id` in the `error` object (if there's an error response) from the verification (payment lookup) API response into your database for further trouble shooting purpose with PayPal support.

Sample API tests by curl commands would be like:

**Step#1 - Getting access token for authentication**

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "<your sandbox APP client>:<your sandbox APP secret>" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Parse the sample response and obtain the access token:

```
{
  "scope": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",
  "access_token": "<Your-Access-Token-for-further-calls>",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "app_id": "APP-6XR95014SS315863X",
  "expires_in": 28800
}
```

**Step#2 - Making the look-up call with the access-token and payment ID (returned by you APP, e.g. PAY-123456789)**

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-123456789 \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <the access token from Step#1>"
```

And you'll get the response similar with this, which contains the payment details you would compare & verify with your order information in the database

```
{
  "proof_of_payment": {
    "adaptive_payment": {
      "pay_key": "AP-70M68096ML426802W",
      "payment_exec_status": "COMPLETED",
      "timestamp": "2013-02-20T00:26:25Z",
      "app_id": "APP-91B933855X481767M"
    }
  },
  "payment": {
    "short_description": "Hipster t-shirt",
    "amount": "9.95",
    "currency_code": "USD"
  },
  "client": {
    "platform": "iOS",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "1.0.0",
    "environment": "live",
    "product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK"
  }
}
```

Comment: thnaks a lot, i will check and let you know, please be here, if i get any doubts , i will ask you.

Comment: as mentioned in link, is i need to run this command in server : `curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment?sort_order=asc&sort_by=update_time \`

Comment: The payload format is incorrect, remove all the string queries and only add PAY-ID with this url for request: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI ; secondly, you would need to add your accessToken with -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer accessToken"...

Comment: You would check and get familar with REST API calls here first : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/

Comment: how we can get the payid ? also if payid is : `100` please give a command that i need to run.

Comment: Pay-ID is within the JSON response on MSDK, obtain that from your APP and pass it to your Magento server. I'm updating the answer for the next step, it won't work with a single command though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113298/discussion-between-pp-pduan-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Comment: mobile app team gave this as pay id : `
PAY-3PJ81320D5045362LK5GB2ZQ` but when i tried this command, its not giving any outputs , can you please give me sample command for the pay-id i mentioned.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, in Step#1 you will need your APP client id & secret (the same APP that your dev team used in your mobile APP with SDK) to get the access token. Only with that you'll be able to use the PAY-ID in Step#2.  I've put the fields with <things you need to fill> and you need to fill in with your actual values (remove the "<>" as well) in my updated answer

Comment: is this command is correct : `curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113387/discussion-between-nsdlfefinedieicbe-and-pp-pduan).

Comment: i posted message in chat, please check it.

Comment: i got reply form paypal team as here : `You will need to complete the whole payment using REST API and they cal look up payment resource.

Create the payment, you will get PAY ID.

Get the approval from the buyer.

Execute the payment, payment completed successfully.

Now call Look up a payment resource with PAY ID, then you will get payment details.

You can find the complete process in the bellow url link :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments/#payment
`

Comment: Check the message in chat please

Comment: please check my reply in chat

Comment: i know you are busy, you post one message in daily morning and again reply next day :)  please help me until this issue will be resolved.

Comment: please check and chat message

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701245/order-confirmation-email-not-working-for-paypal-payment-method?noredirect=1#comment62878691_37701245)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Here are [PayPal docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) on how this should be done.

> To verify a payment, answer the following questions:
>
> - Is the proof of payment authentic?
> - Am I the recipient of the payment?
> - Are the amount and currency correct?
> - Has the payment been previously used?

Payment details by payment id can be get using REST API:

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer accessToken"
```

---

You said that you have Magento website integrated with PayPal already. This means that you have IPN enabled and working. When new payment occur from Android app IPN should trigger and you should get that sale recorded in Magento.

I don't see why should you send transaction data from Android to Magento? In case that you want to know how much sales you got from Android you can use custom fields which are available with PayPal.

Comment: yes, Magento site is integrated with paypal. than when new payment occur from android, than no need to validate the paypal email id & password or some other validation from magento API ? our andriod team is telling its not possible to check in app that user entered correct email id or not ? so to validate these things from magento side, i need to write an API and give to them, using that API they will validate. please guide me in right direction.

Comment: I think you didn't asked question properly :) I am not clear what you are trying to do or validate as you say. When payment is completed, it doesn't matter is Android or web, IPN will triggered and you can record that sale in Magento. What to you mean by "validating paypal email and password"? Can you explain this more? You don't need user's password in order for them to pay you. Or you are talking about accounts on your website?

Comment: you may be right. i am not that much idea about these apis , transaction id, soap and all. validation means, whether email entered by customer is already registered email or not , these kind of validation. means are you telling once we integrate paypal in both magento and if andriod can access paypal through magento , than no need to send any kind of transaction ids to magento for validation ? they said they are getting transaction id by paypal sdk.

Comment: In case that you have registration and user needs to login before doing some payment you need somehow to know which user from your website paid, that is usually done via custom fields. On payment request custom field is set, like user ID from your database, and on IPN call you have that custom field send back by PayPal and you can link payment to your user. If you are only interested in PayPal email address that is also available in IPN request done by PayPal. So... I still don't see any reason for sending payment data from Android to Magento :)

Comment: means is IPN is already builtin with magento code. there is no need to send any transaction id got from andriod to magento 
customer can pay through app. builtin IPN only will take care about validation ?

Comment: please visit [github link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/main/java/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/SampleActivity.java)

& search for "server for verification" , there they mentioned we have to verify with server, i want this.

Comment: I am actually not Android developer so I didn't worked with PayPal Android SDK before but I don't a lot PayPal integration on web and this looks like overkill for me. But it looks to me that you are looking for this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/ and you can get payment data by payment id using REST API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments/#payment.get

Comment: even i am not good in php coding . we are using soap username & api key to connect from magento to andriod. than now i need to write an

api for andriod team to verify payments ? can you please help me for this.

Comment: I didn't worked much with Magento so I can't help you with building API, and your question is not now to build API :) it is PayPal related.

Comment: paypal team provide this [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/GetPayment.php) & they are telling i can use the whole sdk for getting payment details. how i can use this        ? for validation from magento end.

Comment: can you please check updated question & coments of answer posted by other user & me.