# Order confirmation email not working for PayPal payment method

Tags: magento, paypal, smtp, e-commerce

We are not getting order confirmation email if customer placed an order through PayPal in Magento site. But we get the invoice and shipment mails.

We set `Sale : Payment Action` in PayPal configuration.

So once we create the order, along with the order email [it's not going to the customer] I want to send invoice mail also to customer. i=I think this [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-invoice-by-plumrocket-inc.html) will send invoice only once order **status become complete**.

Would [SMTP extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html) work for us?

Is there anything else we need to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?